# Render shortcodes with get_post_custom

Tags: shortcode, array

Wondering if anyone knows how to get a toggle shortcode to render when using: get_post_custom

```
<?php
    $post_customs = get_post_custom();
    //$post_customs = the_sub_field('project_items');
    if(isset($post_customs["project_items"]) && count($post_customs["project_items"]) > 0) {
        $project_items = $post_customs["project_items"][0];
        $projectItems = explode(":",$project_items);
?>
            <?php if(count($projectItems) > 1) {
                $totalProjectItems = $projectItems[1];
                for($i = 0; $i < $totalProjectItems; $i++) {
            ?>

            <?php $pro_item_post = get_post($post_customs["project_items_".$i."_choose_project_item"][0]); ?>
```

Calling the content with:

```
            <aside class="one_half last">

                <?php echo $post_customs["project_items_".$i."_edit_proposal_item"][0]; ?>

            </aside><!--/.one_half -->
```

This renders out the shortcode within the content area i.e.: "[toggle title="Test"] CONTENT" instead of actually rendering it as a toggle. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `do_shortcode()`

```
echo do_shortcode($post_customs["project_items_".$i."_edit_proposal_item"][0]);
```

More : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode